# User Management + FaceBook + Twitter?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook, codeigniter, twitter

Is there any library available for user management with FB & Twitter integrated? My language of choice would be Ruby on Rails/PHP(CodeIgniter FW).

Answer (score 1):

I am using this janrain plugin in Ruby on Rails application. I am sure you can find one for php as well. in fact bundle of options for php :)

http://www.janrain.com/

yeah, just saw the support for php as well

http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled

Answer (score 1):

For Rails I use Devise for all of my use management processing. It does all of the authentication you need. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise